# Android - Webview Javascript to call a function for a specific DIV class

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, onclicklistener

I am loading a JS webpage in my WebView.  The webpage looks like a calendar and has items on the calendar that, when clicked or double-clicked, call functions defined on the page.

When a user taps once on the item, I want it to call the proper function as well as do the same for tapping twice on it.  I know this is android, but users are expecting the function to happen when "double-clicking".

The function for double-clicking the item is:

```
function openPairingDetails(tripSequenceNumber) {
        var url = "/csswa/ea/fa/getPairingDetails.do?popup=true&tripSequenceNumber=" + tripSequenceNumber;
        var features = "height=600,width=900,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no";
        openWindow(url, features);
        return false;
```

For now at least, all the items that the user will be double-clicking are of the same class:

```
<div class="boardpiece clickable" onclick="selectPairing(event, this);" ondblclick="openPairingDetails('5545220');"
```

So, the short version is this:  I need to display the webpage (done) and allow the user to single-click to select the item and double-click to open the item.  Each of these events link to a defined function.  So, do I set up an OnClickListener to initiate a JS function on a single/double click of the DIV CLASS?

edit:  I do not have the luxury of altering the website.

edit 2:  Here is my logic:  Page is displayed with an object.  That object has a specific div class.  The object ID is dynamic so it cannot be used.  The object calls a specific function when either single or double clicked.  Can I set a tap listener to call those specific functions?  In other words - if the user taps once on one of these objects, the "onClick" function is called.  If the user performs a longpress on an object, the "onDblClick" function is called.  Can I set these to call the respective functions?

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
  // some other code here
}

public boolean onLongClick(View view)
  {
    // just showing a Toast here
    return false;
  }
```

Thank you

~ Dan

Answer (score 0):

double click cannot handle it in android webview. Any click listener on webview will work complete webview not on any element.

better u need to implement it on div only with this link

[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1903131.aspx?Trying%20to%20Implement%20Double%20Click%20on%20DIV)

den use javascript bridge interface if u want to some android native related stuff

Comment: Are you suggesting that I edit the website?  If so, this is not an option.  I must work with what I have.  If I didn't state it in my original question, I am willing to use a longpress as a doubletap if that helps.

Comment: @Dan ya but Dan i worked webview, i didnt find any thing like getting a onclick events for div element through android native platform it has be done through javascript bridge. so just sharing my experience, if u find any thing like that please put a comment below for sharing.

Comment: Okay.  I appreciate the response though.  If I find a solution, I will certainly update my post.